# How many active developers in Doctrine, Symfony, Zend Framework and CakePHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, symfony1, doctrine

I want to know how many active developers are working on the following frameworks:  Symfony, Zend Framework and CakePHP and the orm Doctrine. I tried to find this information on repositories but no success...

Comment: why is that important? it doesn't tell that it's better or worse. Only when it's one-man-show project, than it's bit risky ;)

Comment: This belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by finding out? After all, Microsoft Windows has more users than Linux and OSX together. That doesn't mean it's any good, does it?

Comment: I have contributed a patch. Am I an active developer?

Comment: These are real packagist numbers from 2020: https://www.tomasvotruba.com/php-framework-trends/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ohloh](http://ohloh.net) parses many projects' repositories and extracts contributor information.

For example for CakePHP [here](http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp/contributors).

Of course, that depends on all relevant repos being registered with the Ohloh profile. Also, sometimes, different accounts for the same contributor are not recognized. But it should give you a rough idea in any case.

Answer (score 0):

[ZF2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) is on github. 173 forks.

Comment: Gordon is right. I have also a zf2 fork and Im not a developer, but interested ;)

Comment: Forkers definately show some interes in contributing, otherwise you dont need to fork. :)

Comment: As of December 2014, ZF2 has ~3.000 forks with ~5000 stars.

Answer (score 0):

Look for user groups forums etc on Google and Yahoo and here and judge by the number of entries/threads etc.